# Can anyone help me to proof the 2nd expression?

Tags: linear-algebra

We need to proof these expressions when **a** and **b** are real numbers

[image: Question]

Here is what I have tried so far
[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

When $a = 0$ and/or $b = 0$, the inequalities clearly hold. Now consider the case $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$.

Both 2) and 3) reduce to 1). For 2), you have
\begin{align}
a^6 + a^4b^2 + a^2b^4 + b^6 &\text{ vs. } a^6 + 2a^3b^3 + b^6, \\
a^4b^2 + a^2b^4 &\text{ vs. }  2a^3b^3,\\
a^2 + b^2 &\text{ vs. }  2ab.
\end{align}
In the final step, you simply divide both sides by $a^2b^2 > 0$.

For 3), you have
\begin{align}
2a^2+2b^2 &\text{ vs. } a^2 + 2ab + b^2, \\
a^2+b^2 &\text{ vs. } 2ab.
\end{align}
Now just do the same as what you did for 1).